# How can I disable a field in admin customer edit but enable when create new?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, forms

I'm having a enabled field in `admin/customer/index/new` but when forward to `admin/customer/index/edit/id/{id}`, I'd like to have it disabled.
It'd be great if done in PHP.

I notice that both using `base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`

Comment: customer_index_new is your custom created layout  ?

Comment: no mate, I haven't created anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally able to disable it using js, so I leave the solution here.

```
require(['jquery', 'uiRegistry'], function ($, uiRegistry) {
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            var url       = window.location.href;
            var arguments = url.split('/');
            if (jQuery.inArray("id", arguments) !== -1) {
                uiRegistry.get('customer_form.areas.customer.customer.password', function (element) {
                    element.visible(false);
                });
            }
        }) });
```